# Finding DEM for Greece (in high resolution) in order to calculate road slopes?

Tags: data, dem, road, slope, greece

I want to calculate the slope of road segments and I need dem for Greece. Where can I find it? I have found another one but the slopes were huge which is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASTER GDEM V2 provides global elevation at 30-meter resolution 
https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp

available for download through NASA Reverb: https://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/ or USGS: http://gdex.cr.usgs.gov/gdex/